# What installer solution does the JDownloader project uses to create it's installer?

Tags: java, installation, jdownloader

I'm in the search for a installer solution for my application and I like the installer used by JDownloader.

What installer solution does the JDownloader project uses to create it's installer?

Comment: You may want to show a screen shot.  It might be evident just from that.

Answer (score 0):

It uses Install4j: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html